# RK4 to solve Schrödinger equation

Tags: numerical-methods, quantum-mechanics, runge-kutta-methods

Let $m = 1$, $\hbar = 1$, the Schrödinger equation becomes: 
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}(x,t) 
= \frac{i}{2} \left( \nabla^2 - V(x)\right) \psi(x,t) 
\end{equation}
given $x_k = x_0 + kh_x$, define $f_k(t) = \psi(x_k,t)$, then:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial t}(t) = \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}(x_k,t) = F_k(t,f_k(t)) 
\end{equation}
where (aproximating the laplacian):
\begin{align*}
 F_k(t,f_k)&=\frac{i}{2} 
        \left( \frac{\psi(x_k+h_x,t)-2\psi(x_k,t)+\psi(x_k-h_x,t)}{h_x^2}-
        V(x_k)f_k \right) \\
 F_k(t,f_k)&=\frac{i}{2} 
        \left( \frac{f_{k+1}(t)-2f_k(t)+f_{k-1}(t)}{h_x^2}-
        V(x_k)f_k \right)   
\end{align*}
let $t_n = t_0 + nh_t$, define:
\begin{equation}
f_k^n \approx f_k(t_n)
\end{equation}
we want to find 
\begin{equation}
f_{k}^{n+1}
\end{equation}
given that we already know
\begin{equation}
f_k^0 = \psi(x_k,0)
\end{equation}
Using RK4:
\begin{align*}
     k_1 &= F_k(t_n,f_k^n) \\
     k_2 &= F_k(t_n+\frac{h_t}{2},f_k^n +\frac{h_t}{2}k_1) \\
     k_3 &= F_k(t_n+\frac{h_t}{2},f_k^n +\frac{h_t}{2}k_2) \\
     k_4 &= F_k(t_n+h_t,f_k^n + h_tk_3)
\end{align*}
then:
\begin{equation}
 f_k^{n+1} = f_k^n + \frac{h_t}{6}(k_1 + 2k_2 + 2k_3 + k_4) 
\end{equation}
usign derivative:
\begin{align*}
    f_{k+1}(t_n + \frac{h_t}{2}) &= f_{k+1}(t_n) + \frac{\partial f_{k+1}}{\partial t}(t_n) \frac{h_t}{2} \\
    f_{k+1}(t_n + \frac{h_t}{2}) &= f_{k+1}(t_n) + F_{k+1}(t_n, f_{k+1}(t_n))\frac{h_t}{2}
\end{align*}
introducing the notation:
\begin{align*}
    F_{k}^n &= F_k(t_n, f_k^n) \\
    f_{k+1}(t_n + \frac{h_t}{2}) &= f_{k+1}^n + F_{k+1}^n \frac{h_t}{2}
\end{align*}
likewise:
\begin{align*}
    f_{k}(t_n + \frac{h_t}{2})  &= f_{k}^n + F_{k}^n\frac{h_t}{2}\\
    f_{k-1}(t_n + \frac{h_t}{2}) &= f_{k-1}^n + F_{k-1}^n\frac{h_t}{2} 
\end{align*}
replacing:
\begin{align*}
    k_1 = F_k^n &=\frac{i}{2}(\nabla^2 - V)f_k^n \\ 
    k_2 = F_k(t_n+\frac{h_t}{2},f_k^n +\frac{h_t}{2}k_1) &= \frac{i}{2}
    (\nabla^2 - V) \left( f_k^n +\frac{h_t}{2}k_1 \right) \\
    k_3 = F_k(t_n+\frac{h_t}{2},f_k^n +\frac{h_t}{2}k_2) &= 
    \frac{i}{2} 
    \left(
    \nabla^2 \left( f_k^n +\frac{h_t}{2}k_1 \right) 
    - V \left( f_k^n +\frac{h_t}{2}k_2 \right) \right) \\
    k_4 = F_k(t_n+h_t,f_k^n +k_3) &= 
    \frac{i}{2} 
    \left(
    \nabla^2 \left( f_k^n + h_tk_1 \right) 
    - V \left( f_k^n + h_tk_3 \right) 
    \right)
\end{align*}
I am not sure if I arrive at the correct coefficients they don't look like this: [image]